# CSS being rendered as HTML in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

My css file present in css/style.css :

```
body {
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 40px;
 font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #4F5155;
}
```

When I run the site in a browser, there is no styling to the controller page , and the path to the css file returns this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>404 Page Not Found</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
background-color:   #fff;
margin:             40px;
font-family:        Lucida Grande, Verdana, Sans-serif;
font-size:          12px;
color:              #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <h1>404 Page Not Found</h1>
    <p>The page you requested was not found.</p>    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on what's going on here ?

Comment: check your apache rewrite, apache error log, it should stated why file not found (such as refer to wrong DocumentRoot or so)

Comment: The error log doesn't give anything. The access log gives this : 

127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2010:15:58:28 +0530] "GET /c/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 688 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12"
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2010:15:58:29 +0530] "GET /c/index.php/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 539 "http://localhost/c/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stylesheet can't be found, most likely because it isn't on the path you think it is.

Things to check:

- What do you think your stylesheet's path is (i.e. what did you type in the browser to get that 404 error?)
- Where is the file in the filesystem in relation to your CodeIgniter root?
- Are you using a .htaccess file? If so, what's in it? The .htaccess redirection done in CodeIgniter can confuse you.

The "standard" setup for CodeIgniter css files is this:

- Save your css file in a "css" directory in the root of your CodeIgniter install, i.e. alongside the top-level index.php and .htaccss.
- Make sure your .htaccess rewrite excludes the css directory, e.g.:
  `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)` <-- note "css" is among the patterns to *avoid* rewrites for here. Otherwise CodeIgniter will think that "css" is a controller, not the actual directory on disk.
- Include your CSS file in your HTML file using something like: `<link rel="stylesheet" href='<?php echo base_url()?>css/style.css' type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />`.
- Obviously, make sure that your `base_url` is set correctly in your application's config\config.php file.

Comment: Ah ! Got it ! My htaccess file was missing the css directory! Thanks so much !

Comment: @Hardik No problem. That's why you weren't seeing an error in the Apache error log; at the Apache level, there was no error. Apache's .htaccess mechanism was successfully pointing the request for the css file at CodeIgniter's main entry point. Then *CodeIgniter* was trying to find a controller called "css", failing, and manually throwing the CodeIgniter custom 404 page/error back at you. (If you look in application\errors\error_404.php, you'll see the source of the 404 page you were being shown.)